# working with services for data manipulation angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, angularjs-service

```
app.service('cityService',['$http',function($http){
this.get = function(){
        $http({
            method : 'get',
            url : API_SERVER+'city/'
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }).error(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
 }
```

I am trying to use the service to fetch the data from the server but the problem is when i use the service to store the data in scope variable. i get `undefined`. I m receiving the data since the data is showing in console + the service is working too when i add in controller but the data isn't saving in any variable. I used `$timeout` to delay the checking of variable but still no luck. I also used `.then()` but it show `undefined` for the service when i add with service...

```
app.controller('Controller',['cityService',function(cityService){
$scope.temp = {};
$scope.temp = cityService.get();
}]);
```

Anyway to pass the data from service to controller?
Note:
Also tried to store the data into service variable and return the service variable

```
this.var = ''
this.get = function(){
    $http({
        method : 'get',
        url : API_SERVER+'city/'
    }).success(function(response){
        this.var = response
        console.log(this.var);
        return this.var;
    }).error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

the data is storing into variable but in the end isn't passing to the controller.
any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

`this.get` method of your service should return a `promise` object from, so that caller can call `.then` method *to get `response`* or *to chain the promise*.

**Service**

```
app.service('cityService', ['$http', function($http) {
    this.get = function() {
        return $http.get(API_SERVER + 'city/');
        //below would work but use upper one smaller version
        //return $http({
        //    method : 'get',
        //   url : API_SERVER+'city/'
        //});
    };
}]);
```

And then while accessing data inside your controller, you could place `.then` function over it to get response from it.

Additionally you missed to add `$scope` dependency inside your controller DI array.

```
app.controller('Controller', ['cityService', '$scope',
  function(cityService, $scope) {
    $scope.temp = {};
    cityService.get().then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      $scope.temp = response.data;
    });
  }
]);
```

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/vc5St3YjQMdDsSzmtQUQ?p=preview)

Comment: $http return a promise by default...check angularjs docs... 
tried but i get error .....then() can not be set to undefined.
can u show a jsfiddle with working code? coz mine isnt working

Comment: @ScienCeSubject check out updated answer & plunkr :)

Comment: it kinda helped... changed my logic to achieve what i wanted... but still thnx for helping me out